# Returning dataframe of multiple rows/columns per one row of input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am using apply to leverage one dataframe to manipulate a second dataframe and return results. Here is a simplified example that I realize could be more easily answered with "in" logic, but for now let's keep the use of .apply() as a constraint:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B'],'Value':range(1,3)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A']*3+['B']*4+['C'],'Value':range(1,9)})

def filter_df(x, df):
    return df[df['Name']==x['Name']]

df1.apply(filter_df, axis=1, args=(df2,   ))
```

Which is returning:

```
0      Name  Value
0    A      1
1    A      2
2   ...
1      Name  Value
3    B      4
4    B      5
5   ...
dtype: object
```

What I would like to see instead is one formated DataFrame with Name and Value headers.  All advice appreciated!

```
Name    Value
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   A   3
3   B   4
4   B   5
5   B   6
6   B   7
```

Comment: `df2[df2['Name'].isin(df1['Name'])]`

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I noted in the question, I realize I have simplified my use case down to the point of being answered by the "in"/"isin" logic, but that will not always be true and I would like to figure out how to return dataframes from an apply in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this cannot be done solely based on apply, you need [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
result = pd.concat(df1.apply(filter_df, axis=1, args=(df2,)).to_list())
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  Name  Value
0    A      1
1    A      2
2    A      3
3    B      4
4    B      5
5    B      6
6    B      7
```

Comment: My hero! Thank you very much; this is clever.

Comment: @TomH Glad I could help :)